# Batch Script that will Zip all the files in a folder

Tags: batch-file

I need to zip  content of a folder with the help of batch script.
I need to complete this task without third party application.

Thanks in advance.
Prakhar

Comment: [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27279354/1683264).

Comment: Without a third party you ill need to create your own compressing algorithm and it ill take a huge amount of time. Save yourself from this pain and use some kind of zip library/plugin

Comment: I need to do it without any third application help. it is one of instruction for this work for me.

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compres-zip-and-uncopress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-batch-f

Comment: is there any way through which we can compress only files inside that folder , not the subfolders..

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's probably what you don't want, but..
Maybe this will help:

```
"%homedrive%\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -ep1 NameThisFile.rar" "YourFolderToZip\*.*" >nul
```

This will zip all the files in the actual folder, so it won't zip the files from the subfolders.

Or it can look like this:

```
"WinRAR.exe" a -ep1 NameThisFile.rar" "YourFolderToZip\*.*" >nul
```

But that will work only if the executable(WinRAR.exe) is in the same folder as the batch file.