# Compress .Bak file using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have some software I use for business that backs up a database every day.
This leads to multiple large .Bak files (in excess of 2GB) on my storage drives.

Is there a way to compress the file, then delete the uncompressed version using a batch file?

NOTE: the name of the file contains the date it was created, making each filename unique. I also have to keep all the backups, as per some or other regulations.

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compres-zip-and-uncopress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-batch-f

Comment: and this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/27279354/1683264